# Is there a support to pass url of a external static template to ngTemplateOutlet

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a template

```
<ng-template #defaultTabButtons>
    <div class="default-tab-buttons">
      This is really a massive template so I 
      want to be in a separate static HTML file 
    </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-container 
   *ngTemplateOutlet="myTemplate">    
</ng-container>
```

Is there a way that I can have a separate template which I can reference to by passing a templateUrl instead of passing a TemplateRef myTemplate, I couldn't find it in the documentation, may be there is a way around. If anybody knows, it will be much appreciated.

Comment: you can achieve by using dynamic component loading

Comment: Can you provide the example. Even that be so, it will ask to be a component, what if I want it to be simply a template that can be reference to a ngTemplateOutlet?

Comment: What about using ngComponentOutlet?

Comment: The thing about using ngComponentOutlet is to create a component. I want to know a way (if there is) where this can be solved without creating an entirely new component. I think there must be a support for templateUrls in angular. Which is not. I will create a PR to this.